# How to save installations across sessions?

Tags: python-2.7, session, google-colaboratory

In Colaboratory, is there a way to save library installations across sessions? If so how, can I do that? I'd like to learn more about Colaboratory session management in general.

Currently, everytime I have to import, for e.g. a cv2 module(as this is not available by default), I need to reinstall the module with `!pip install opencv-python` along with it's dependencies that provide for shared objects, through a `!apt=-get package-name`.

Answer (score 5):

VMs time out after a period of inactivity, so you'll want to structure your notebooks to install custom dependencies if needed.

A typical pattern is to have a cell at the top of your notebook that executes `apt` and `pip` install commands as needed.

In the case of opencv, that would look something like:

`!apt install -y -qq libsm6 libxext6 && pip install -q -U opencv-python`

(Takes ~7 seconds for me on a fresh VM.)